# Integral in $\mathbb R^3$ and $\Gamma$-function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, gamma-function

How one can show this equality? 
$$
\iiint_V x^{a-1}y^{b-1}z^{c-1}\,dxdydz = \dfrac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a+b+c+1)},
$$
where $V$ is simplex $x\geqslant0, y\geqslant0, z\geqslant0, x+y+z\leqslant1 $.

Only thing I thought is changing variable in some way but it didn't help me.

Comment: I'm thinking about changing variable as $u=-\ln x, v =-\ln y , w=-\ln z$

Answer (score 4):

That's actually quite a nice one. If you know Quantum Field Theory you might have heard of Feynman parameters? They come in handy here (beware rigour, I'm a physicist :D) So, how can you prove the above? First note

$$\frac{1}{AB}=\int_{0}^1dxdy \delta(x+y-1)\frac{1}{(xA+yB)^2}.$$ This can be proven straightforwardly. Moreover, it can be generalized

$$\frac{1}{A_1\cdots A_n}=\int_0^1 dx_1 \cdots dx_n \delta\left(\sum_i x_i -1\right)\frac{(n-1)!}{(x_1A_1+\ldots+x_nA_n)^n}$$ (Proof by induction.)

Now, you can differentiate wrt to the $A_i$ to find

$$\frac{1}{A_1^{m_1} \cdots A_n^{m_n}}=\int_0^1 dx_1 \cdots dx_n \delta\left(\sum_i x_i-1\right)\frac{\prod_i x_i^{m_i-1}}{\left(\sum_i x_i A_i\right)^{\sum m_i}}\cdot \frac{\Gamma(m_1+\ldots+m_n)}{\Gamma(m_1)\Gamma(m_2) \cdots \Gamma(m_n)}.$$

Set all $A_i$ to one and you essentially have your statement. This is also stated in the QFT book by Peskin/Schroeder on p. 190.

Comment: Well I'm going to spend some time to understand this (actually now I'm taking a course in QM). Unfortunately I should explain how to solve this problem to my calculus class and I think that my students have not yet heard about QFT. So I looking for some of elementary explanation.

Comment: Well, there's actually no reference in my derivation to QFT. Just some playing around with integral identities. I just meant that these sorts of integrals appear in QFT loop computations...that's all :) Other than that, it's pretty straightforward maths :)

Comment: This is very nice even though the method doesn't work for non-integer $a,b,c$. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how the solution,

$$ I=\iiint_V x^{a-1}y^{b-1}z^{c-1}\,dx\,dy\,dz = \int_{0}^{1}x^{a-1}dx\int_{0}^{1-x}y^{b-1}dy\int_{0}^{1-x-y}z^{c-1}dz $$

**Added:**

$$I = \frac{1}{c}\int_{0}^{1}x^{a-1}dx\int_{0}^{1-x}y^{b-1}(1-x-y)^c\,dy $$

Using the change of variables $t=\frac{y}{1-x}$ and [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) after factoring out $(1-x)$, we have

$$ I = \frac{1}{c}{\frac{\Gamma\left( c \right) \Gamma 
 \left( b \right) }{\Gamma\left(c+b+1 \right) }}
\int_{0}^{1}x^{a-1}(1-x)^{c+b}\,dx $$

$$ I = {\frac{\Gamma\left( c \right) \Gamma 
 \left( b \right) }{\Gamma\left(c+b+1 \right) }}\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(c+b+1)}{\Gamma(a+b+c+1)} = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a+b+c+1)}.$$

**Note:** The [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) is defined as

$$ \beta(x,y) = \int_0^1t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,dt \!,\quad \textrm{Re}(x), \textrm{Re}(y) > 0.\, $$

Answer (score -1):

You remember beta-function? $B(z,w)=\displaystyle \int_0^1 t^{z-1}(1-t)^{w-1} dt$, you are going to use it and make some substitutions. You take the integral one at a time while making the substitution and see what happen. Am sure you will get it.

Comment: I am sure the Riemann Hypothesis is correct.  Yet these mathematicians insist on trying to prove it.

Comment: Ron Gordon what is your point?

Comment: You failed to present an answer.

Comment: @RonGordon, sorry for my lack of knowledge on the subject, but what Riemann's Hypothesis has to do with YYG's answer?

Comment: @user1620696: nothing.  Zero.  Which is about as much use as this answer is in solving the problem.